# Dart new install hello world import error

Tags: dart

I've just installed the Dart SDK on a server, and following the tutorial at https://dart.dev/tutorials/server/get-started

Have done the following

```
mkdir cli
cd cli
stagehand console-full
```

I can see this has installed various files into the cli director, including..

```
bin/main.dart
lib/cli.dart
```

However (I am in the cli dir), when I run

```
dart bin/main.dart
```

I get

```
Error: Could not resolve the package 'cli' in 'package:cli/cli.dart'.
```

I am inside the cli dir. I can see the cli.dart file is in the lib folder. main.dart has

```
import 'package:cli/cli.dart' as cli;
```

I've tried adjusting the package location at the top of the main.dart file, eg tried things like

```
import 'package:cli/lib/cli.dart' as cli;
import 'lib/cli.dart' as cli;
```

etc, but none seem to work.

As this is a basic hello world that should work out of the box, I feel like I'm missing something (I've also got $HOME/.pub-cache/bin in my path).

What have I done wrong or have missing ?

..

Ok, I have it working as...

```
import '../lib/cli.dart' as cli;
```

But something feels wrong as I've had to edit this away from the tutorial. Is there some setting that could be missing to say where a default package is located, or is it just that the tutorial has a bug ?

Comment: did you run `pub get` before running the app?

Comment: Interesting, yes I did, and whilst it looked like it ran ok, scrolling back up, after it ran, it downloads loads, and then gets to http and shows: Downloading http 0.12.0+2...
Write failed (OS Error: Broken pipe, errno = 32), port = 0
I've just ran it a couple of times again, and looks like it's completed ok without that error, and now I don't get the package error, so maybe it was a server side issues. Thanks dev-aentgs, that may have figured it.